# Finding basis of complex vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, vector-spaces

How to find a basis for the vector space $P = \lbrace(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{C}^3 : 2x + 2y + 2 iz = 0\rbrace$ over $\mathbb C$?

I believe this is what is called a hyperplane, is that correct?

And how can I check that it actually spans $P$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is a hyperplane. And you do it exactly as you would have done it over the reals. For instance, since$$P=\{(-y-iz,y,z)\mid y,z\in\mathbb C\},$$then $P=\bigl\langle\{(-1,1,0),(-i,0,1)\}\bigr\rangle$, and, since the set $\{(-1,1,0),(-i,0,1)\}$ is linearly independent, it is a basis of $P$.

Comment: Thank you! May I ask how you show that the basis spans the hyperplane?

Comment: Because$$(-y-iz,y,z)=y(-1,0,1)+z(-i,0,1).$$

Comment: Ah yes, thank you!